# Conversion of large UNICODE csv file to UTF-8 csv without opening it

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, export-to-csv

I have exported a UNICODE csv file(22 million records, Size 4.32 gb). As the file is so big it cant be opened in Excel.I need to convert this file to UTF-8 without opening it. What are the possible options?

OR which tool can I use to open it and then convert to UTF-8 csv?

Regards,
Sayli

Answer (score 2):

Using the `iconv` program you can convert the encoding of any file.

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 < input.csv > output.csv
```